# How to create a many-to-many mapping in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

Here is the case, I have 2 entities, such as Contract、Media。

```
public class Media : Entity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool Enabled
    *//other properties can be ignored..*
}

public class Contract : Entity
{
    public string Code {get; set;}
    *//other properties can be ignored..*
}
```

Contract has many Medias, it seems that they are many to many.

**But!! at ef code first, i need 3 more fields  in the ContractMedia table(ef auto generated).
such as StartDate,EndDate and Price. these could not be added in Media entity.**

How to map at this case??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you want to create many to many relationship with additional data in association table, you have to make the association table as entity. The pure many to many relationship is only in pure table with entity id's.

In you case it will be:

```
public class Media // One entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> ContractMedias { get; set; }
}

public class Contract // Second entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> ContractMedias { get; set; }
}

public class ContractMedia // Association table implemented as entity
{
    public int MediaId { get; set; }
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Media Media { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

And after you created models/entities, you need to define relationships in context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<ContractMedia>()
       .HasKey(c => new { c.MediaId, c.ContractId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ContractMedias)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContractId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Media>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ContractMedias)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.MediaId);  
}
```

Also you can refer to these links: 
[Many to many mapping with extra fields in Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153390/many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-fields-in-fluent-api)
[Entity Framework CodeFirst many to many relationship with additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434125/entity-framework-codefirst-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-information)
[Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Comment: I think `ContractMedia` should not have the inverse nav collections: `Medias` & `Contracts`. These should instead be forward nav properties.

I was getting extra fields in the many-many lookup table until I changed the inverse (collection) properties to forward properties.

Comment: @IAbstract I think you can be right because I don't retrieve value from the navigation to the common table. And I am sure it is due to the nav collections

Comment: @IAbstract: How do you change "inverse (collection) properties to forward properties."?

Comment: Is this possible with attributes?

Comment: @IAbstract in order to not have double fields, you have to link both navigation properties on each end.

you can achieve this by using the inverseproperty attribute.
for this example you can add

[InverseProperty("Medias ")]
public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> ContractMedias { get; set; }

in the media class

Comment: @SouhaiebBesbes I got this error Multiplicity '1' is not compatible with the property.

Answer (score 25):

Adding to @Tomas answer without having to use Fluent API.

```
public class Media // One entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> ContractMedias { get; set; }
}

public class Contract // Second entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> ContractMedias { get; set; }
}

public class ContractMedia // Association table implemented as entity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Media")]
    public int MediaId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Contract")]
    public int ContractId { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Media Media { get; set; }

    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core needs to use Fluent API but it would look like this:

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
            .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
            .UsingEntity<PostTag>(
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                    .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId),
                j => j
                    .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
                    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId),
                j =>
                {
                    j.Property(pt => pt.PublicationDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                    j.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
                });
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration