# Add a field to a relation table and access row values through code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

Using EF code first and Fluent, I've created two tables containing data and a third table which is the "relation table" (not sure what the 'official' word for it is?). Each row holds Id's from both tables and defines a many-to-many relation between the two.

The tables hold purchase orders and products. Now I need to specify the amount of products in a purchase order as well, so my most logical conclusion was to add a field in the relation table that specifies the quantity, so that the table will become:

```
orderId | productId | quantity
  83923 |    867392 |      100
  83923 |    865392 |      250
  83923 |    323392 |       50
```

Is this possible using EF code first? I couldn't find a way, but it's hard to search for a solution since I find it hard to concisely describe what I need to do.
I thought I could add a field using the designer, which works, but I have no idea how to access the value through code now.

My tables: 
The field/table names are all in Dutch, but hopefully it's understandable & readable.

```
-- Purchase orders
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InkoopOrders] (
    [InkoopOrderId]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Kenmerk]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InkoopOrders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InkoopOrderId] ASC)
);

-- Products
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artikelen] (
    [ArtikelId]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Kenmerk]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Artikelen] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ArtikelId] ASC)
);

-- Relation table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InkoopOrderArtikel] (
    [InkoopOrderId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ArtikelId]     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InkoopOrderArtikel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InkoopOrderId] ASC, [ArtikelId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InkoopOrderArtikel_dbo.InkoopOrders_InkoopOrderId] FOREIGN KEY ([InkoopOrderId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[InkoopOrders] ([InkoopOrderId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InkoopOrderArtikel_dbo.Artikelen_ArtikelId] FOREIGN KEY ([ArtikelId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Artikelen] ([ArtikelId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This was achieved through creating the two models, and defining the relation in Fluent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InkoopOrder>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Artikelen)
    .WithMany(a => a.InkoopOrders)
    .Map(
        m => {
            m.MapLeftKey("InkoopOrderId");
            m.MapRightKey("ArtikelId");
            m.ToTable("InkoopOrderArtikel");
        }
    );
```

Comment: it's called _join / junction table_ for table that maps many to many relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF, in may to many relationships, the association table can only have the Key columns of the related tables. So, no, you cannot do that with a many to many using EF. If you wanted to do this, you'd need to specify two one-to-may relationships (from both many to many tables, to the association table). [Look at this SO answer for a full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/entity-framework-many-to-many-mapping#answer-19343047).

However, I don't understand why you want to use a many to many. You simply need to use the classical `Order` table with a child `OrderDetail` table that has the `ProductId`, `UnitPrice`, `Units`, `Total`, and so on. Forget about using the many to many for this case. It's much easier in this way.