# EF Code First 6 and many-to-many with entity mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

Following the example in this question: [How to create a many-to-many mapping in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework) I would like to have a table mapping where I can add or remove many-to-many relationships without having to go through the `Media` or `Contract` entities.

Essentially, I would like to have:

```
public class Media // One entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract // Second entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set }

    public virtual ICollection<Media> Medias { get; set; }
}

public class ContractMedia // Association table implemented as entity
{
    public Media Media { get; set; }
    public int MediaId { get; set; }

    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to configure this scenario using the FluentAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik not with the ContractMedia entity, but you can:

```
public class Media // One entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract // Second entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractMedia> Medias { get; set; }
}

public class ContractMedia // Association table implemented as entity
{
    public Media Media { get; set; }
    public int MediaId { get; set; }

    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Media // One entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract // Second entity table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set }

    public virtual ICollection<Media> Medias { get; set; }
}
```

that will lead to the creation of a non mapped association table in the database.