# Entity framework allow duplicates in many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have 2 object - parents and childs in relationship many-to-many, the issue is that 1 parent can have 2 the same childs, but EF saves this relationship only 1 time.

I found only 2 working solutions:

1. add `count` column into table and manually fill it
2. not use many-to-many, but split it into one-to-many and many-to-one
   but I do not like this solutions, because I hope that there could be some more simple solution.

Could you help me please?

EDIT:
Example of junction table:

1-1

1-1

1-2

1-3

2-3

Code:
model

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> childs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> parents { get; set; }
}
```

DB context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().
HasMany(i => i.childs).
WithMany(i2 => i2.parents).
Map(
m =>
{
m.MapLeftKey("parentId");
m.MapRightKey("childId");
m.ToTable("itemRelationship");
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, parent can have multiple child and children will have parent. Then it can be done in 1-N relationship. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Post what your code looks like, and what EF configuration method you are using for more help.

Comment: `1 parent can have 2 the same childs` - this is confusing, how are children considered as ***the same***? Without more explanation, I assume they are actually 1 child when you say they are the same.

Comment: as I understand the junction table (or join table) here has a primary key of 2 combined columns. Your example shows that there are 2 duplicated keys (both are `1-1`).

Comment: Yes Hopeless, you are right

Comment: I remove keys from join table to be able to do such thing

Comment: It is generally a good idea not to leave M-M to be resolved automatically. In fact, in many cases the junction table has business meaning that the analyst may have to consider. Split the M-M to 3 separate entities. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational databases are about **sets**. A set is a distinct collection of identified entities. Your junction table however, the way you're picturing it, is a **bag**. This violates the fundamentals of relational theory. As usual, one violation gives rise to other violations. Not having a unique primary key, an identity, is the next one. Not being able to refer to these junction records by foreign keys, should you want that, is another one.

So just don't do it.

I think the mistake here is that you want to express the fact "`A` has `n` instances of `B`" by the number of rows you create. But this number is an attribute of the association.

Let's look at an example: Articles and Words.

You could express the relation between `Article` and `Word` by a pure many-to-many association. This association expresses: *this* `Article` contains *these* `Word`s. Watch the demonstrative pronouns (this, these). They imply identity. There will be one instance of each article and one instance of each word in the database.

If you want to store the number of times a word occurs, you have to add this number as an attribute to the association. A fact is never modelled by a number of rows. The single row describes the fact "this `Article` has `n` occurrences of that `Word`". In Entity Framework this means that the association becomes a class in the class model, for instance `ArticleWord`. The multiplicities of the association are `Article` 1-n `ArticleWord` n-1 `Word`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to first define the relationship table. The primary key of that table will be a combination of the 2 foreign keys that it contains, it will allow that composite key to look like :

1-1,

2-1,

2-2

but not :

1-1

1-1

1-2

2-1

Comment: yes, my db does not contain duplicities, but i want my db to contain it

Comment: In that case, don't declare any primary key, instead just declare them as "Unique",  it'll solve everything

Comment: yes, when I load data from dbs, I want to have 1-1 inside my list of model class inserted 2 time, not only 1 time

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gert about the core concept of relational data is sets. To that end I recommend you find another thing to make them unique. Like adding a timestamp or created by date. If you really need to get duplicates in there. But this is again going back to relational data being normalized into sets. Here is a link about [DB Normalization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-normalization-introduction/)

```
[Key, Column(Order =2), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Timestamps are mostly for concurrency but you might be able to add them to a key.

I'm also curious as to what the scenario you have that would need duplicates in a many to many table. Two records with the only two columns being exactly the same, means that the relationship being expressed twice, it doesn't create an additional relationship.

It's like saying my sister is my sister, having it be said that she's my sister again didn't change the fact that she's my sister, it didn't give me two of her, she was still in the collection, she can't be in the collection twice because of database normalization. I can count her twice in my collection but that doesn't change that fact that there is only one of her (in the other table). If there needs to be two of her there should be another record with a different Id.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have duplicate records on n:n relationship :

```
public class Playlist : BaseEntity
{
    public Collection<Track>? Tracks { get; set; }
}
public class Track: BaseEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<Playlist>? Playlists { get; set; }
}
public class PlaylistTrack
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlaylistId { get; set; }
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
}
//....

public DbSet<PlaylistTrack> PlaylistTrack { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Tracks)
        .WithMany(a => a.Playlists)
        .UsingEntity<PlaylistTrack>(a =>
            a.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        );
}
```

to insert records:

```
var pt = new PlaylistTrack()
{
    PlaylistId = playlist.Id,
    TrackId = track.Id
};
db.PlaylistTrack.Add(pt);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```