# Entity Framework - many-to-many relation with allowing duplicate relations

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I want to create `Many-To-Many` relationship which **allowing me duplicated relations**, like this:

```
A | B
-----
1 | a
1 | a
2 | b
2 | b
etc
```

But EF create mapping table like this:

```
AB:
 - AId: PK, FK
 - BId: PK, FK
```

and this doesn't allow duplicated relations.

How I create mapping table like this:

```
AB:
 - Id, PK
 - AId: FK
 - BId: FK
```

Comment: Why do you need these duplicates? There are [very good reasons *not* to want this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32646317/861716)

Comment: I  know that the relational database is about `sets` I read that. So I want to has `**PK**`, `FK`, `FK` and get well set. The sing what I want - there is `Patient` and `Procedure`. `Patient` can has multiple same `Procedure`

Comment: The only thing these duplicates tell you is the number of duplicate procedures a patient has been subjected to. Why not just store this number in one record and increment it when necessary?