# Entity Framework One to Many, Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm building an api using asp.net web api for an application that needs to track all the activities performed by users. So in every table I need to have createdUser and updatedUser field with their dates. But I faced some challenges on how to go about.

Here are my concerns:

1. How can I have that in the User table itself? Which type of relationship do I need for that?
2. I have a privilege table than can be created by required users. What type of relationship can I have between the Privilege and the User table?

I'm new to Entity Framework so I need some guides. Please can anyone be very kind to provide some help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think u wil need to have that logic in the user table itself.
   U can add extra colomn's to each table with CreUser,CreDate, LModUser, LModDate.
   Or U can create an extra table like 
   Entity_ID, Record_ID, User_ID, ModDate, IsCreated.
   (or with other logic)
2. search for many to many relations on google. or:

[How to create a many-to-many mapping in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework)

this is a nice tutorial for all kind of relationships in EF for core
http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration