# How can i add extra column to third table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

Assume i have two entities, `User` and `Notification`:

```
public class User
{
[Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

// other public properties


// Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}



public class Notification
{

    [Key]
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }

// other public properties

    // Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

I'm simply adding `many-to-many` Relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Notifications)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserNotifications");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("NotificationId");
            });
```

But what happens if i want to add extra column to this table which name is **'Status'** ? I thought i can use `AddColumn` but then how can i access this column and get it's value ? How can i accomplish this?  I want to check whether the user read notification or not. Any suggestions would be great,thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you can't just add the column and map it? ...

Comment: I don't know too much about fluent API and mapping,i'm just confusing about how can i access that column from my context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add extra field like "Status" in the relationship. You need to have a dummy table for that.
 And i think your question is same as the following answer 
[Many to Many mapping with extra fields in Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153390/many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-fields-in-fluent-api) 
May be this would help.

> User
>   Notification
>   UserNotification (dummy table) where you put your **Status** field