# ASP.net create many to many entity in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

I'm trying to create an many to many entity in asp.net C#. I have looked at the student/course example before and it is logical but something is literally wrong when I try use it in my own code.

Here is the code where I'm stuck.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BuyWeapon(int weaponId)
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var ctx = new DAL.ProjectStrawberryEntities();

        Character character = ctx.Characters.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccountId == currentUserId);
        Weapon weapon = ctx.Weapons.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == weaponId);

        if (character.Gold - weapon.Price >= 0)
        {
            // Add weapon to character

            character.Gold -= (int)weapon.Price;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The only properties `Character` and `Weapon` has is `WeaponCharacter`, which is my bridge table for `Weapon` and `Character`.

Here are my `Character` and `Weapon` models from my database.

```
public partial class Character
{
    public Character()
    {
        this.WeaponCharacters = new HashSet<WeaponCharacter>();
    }

    *Removed wall of propeties*

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WeaponCharacter> WeaponCharacters { get; set; }
}

public partial class Weapon
{
    public Weapon()
    {
        this.WeaponCharacters = new HashSet<WeaponCharacter>();
    }

    *Removed wall of propeties*

    public virtual WeaponType WeaponType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WeaponCharacter> WeaponCharacters { get; set; }
}

public partial class WeaponCharacter
{
    public int CharacterId { get; set; }
    public int WeaponId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
    public virtual Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}
```

I cropped out some properties since they are unnecessary.
[image]

Shouldn't `Character` have an `ICollection<Weapon>`? Am I wrong to use a many to many relation for this?

The goal I'm trying to reach is: I want a character to buy a weapon, it is possible to buy several of the same weapon but only once per click.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong as I'm used to EntityFramework for Code-First aproach, but shouldn't your `Character` class have an `ICollection<Weapon>` property instead of 'WeaponCharacter'? On my experience (With EF, latest version) the ICollection would be automatically mapped to the WeaponCharacter table as you add items to that collection.

Example of a working many-to-many relationship, using EF-CodeFirst, where `Prescricao` has a many-to-many relationship with `Remedio`:

```
public class Prescricao
{
    // Hidden Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Remédios prescritos para o paciente.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Remedio> Remedios { get; set; }

    public Prescricao()
    {
        Remedios = new List<Remedio>();
    }

}

public class Remedio
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prescrições que incluem o remédio.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Prescricao> Prescricoes { get; set; }

    public Remedio()
    {
        Prescricoes = new List<Prescricao>();
    }
```

Adding something to the relationship:

```
var pres1 = new Classes.Prescricao()
        {
            DataEmissao = DateTime.Now,
            DataLimite = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
            Descricao = "Prescrição teste.",
            Medico = m1,
            Paciente = p1,
            Status = Classes.PrescricaoStatus.Pendente
        };
var r1 = new Classes.Remedio()
        {
            NomeComercial = "Aspirina",
            PrecoMedio = 12.49m,
            PrincipioAtivo = "Whatever",
            Status = Classes.RemedioStatus.Aprovado
        };

        context.Remedios.Add(r1);
        pres1.Remedios.Add(r1);
        context.Prescricoes.Add(pres1);
```

(Was going to add this as a comment as I don't think this solves the issue at hand but I can't comment just yet)

Comment: That's what I thought too, that `Character` should have an `ICollection<Weapon>`. I think something gone wrong when I added an extra column to the bridge table as I've done. I don't see how else I could solve this problem.

Comment: Is the field `Quantity` really required? What would caracterize the "same" weapon? If the weapon has the same attributes and a different ID, you could remove the `Quantity` field and use a Linq query to recover how many weapons of the same type a character has.

Edit: Would this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153390/many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-fields-in-fluent-api) help you? Seems like the guy also had an issue with an extra-field in a Many-To-Many relationship.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if I'm thinking correctly to use a many to many in this situation. The field `Quantity` is as it says, "User 1 has 2 Quanities of Weapon 1". I dont think it's possible to have two identical entries in a many to many? like "User1, Weapon1" twice? That question, was he using code first? I'm going database first.

Comment: Oh, true, he was using a Code-First aproach. And I don't think it would be possible as it might hurt the Primary Key constraint on the relationship table. How about adding a `Quantity` property to the `Weapon` class? That way you can move it away from the `WeaponCharacter` table and you would still be able to quantify the ammount of weapons a character has!

Comment: I will give that a try later!