# Several characters can have several weapons and several of same kind

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

I have a little tricky many to many question. I have two classes `Character` and `Weapon`. These two have a bridge table called `WeaponCharacter`, this is a many to many relationship.

[image]

At this moment, A `Character` can own one `weapon` of each kind, but a `Character` can't own two identical `Weapons`. Picture belows describes how I want to do.

[image]

The upper part is how the code is currently, and below is how I want it to be, or a similar solution.

This is the method that handles the transaction for buying weapons.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BuyWeapon(int weaponId)
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var ctx = new DAL.ProjectStrawberryEntities();

        Character character = ctx.Characters.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccountId == currentUserId);
        Weapon weapon = ctx.Weapons.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == weaponId);

        if (character.Gold - weapon.Price >= 0)
        {
            character.Weapons.Add(weapon);
            character.Gold -= (int)weapon.Price;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Game");
    }
```

**What I've done:**

I did add Quantity once in `WeaponCharacter` but then the `ICollections` for `Weapon` and `Character` got really messed up.

This can be read here: [ASP.net create many to many entity in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608596/asp-net-create-many-to-many-entity-in-c-sharp)

**Goal:**

I want a character to be able to own mulitple copies of same weapon aswell.

Comment: It's as Sean Lange says, I want a character to be able to own multiple copies of the same weapon. Is many to many wrong in this situation? Could probably be easier just to make an inventory table, that takes weaponIds.

Comment: you might be better off in the long run if  you remove the quantity column and just have a table with `WeaponCharacterId` (Key),  `WeaponId` and `CharacterId`, and just keep inserting the same weapon and character id's.  This would give you flexibility to have different optimizations for the same weapon for each character

Comment: @JamieD77 that's sounds a lot easier. Being alone in a project tends to keep your thinking inside the box sometimes. I will go with that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JamieD77 mentioned in comments.

> you might be better off in the long run if you remove the quantity column and just have a table with WeaponCharacterId (Key), WeaponId and CharacterId, and just keep inserting the same weapon and character id's. This would give you flexibility to have different optimizations for the same weapon for each character.