# How can I configure many-to-many relationship to my own created entity in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have some classes:

```
public class Values : Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Values_ID { get; set; }    
        [Required]
        public string Values_Name { get; set; }    
        [Required]
        public int ValuesNumeric { get; set; }    
        public virtual ICollection<ValuesMetrics> ValuesMetrics { get; set; }
    }

public class GQMetric : Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int GQMetric_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string GQMetricName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Importance_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual List<GQMetricsQuestions> GQMetricsQuestions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ValuesMetrics> ValuesMetrics { get; set; }

        public virtual ImportanceScale ImportanceScale { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to create many-to-many relationship to my own created class `ValuesMetrics`, not to automatically generated table by entity framework. I have tried a lot of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342908/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-mapping-in-entity-framework), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153390/many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-fields-in-fluent-api) but none of it did not work. Eventually, I did this:

```
public class ValuesMetrics : Entity
    {
        public int GQMetric_ID { get; set; }
        public int Value_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual GQMetric GQMetric { get; set; }
        public virtual Values Values { get; set; }
    }
```

FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ValuesMetrics>()
               .HasKey(c => new { c.GQMetric_ID, c.Value_ID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<GQMetricsQuestions>()
               .HasKey(c => new { c.GQMetric_ID, c.Question_ID });
```

but created table (`ValuesMetrics`) have an excessive relationship (GQMetrics_GQMetric_ID). I need only two primary keys from `Values` and `GQMetrics` tables
[image: excessive relationship]

Can you advice me how to solve this problem? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied @Esteban 's solution from the link already referenced by you: [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

Basically I did the following three changes:

1. Used POCO entities instead of inheriting from `Entity` class
2. Removed EF attributes, since we'll be using fluent API anyway
3. Changed fluent API configuration

Resulting code:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Values> Values { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GQMetric> GqMetric { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ValuesMetrics> ValuesMetrics { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Values>().HasKey(values => values.Values_ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GQMetric>().HasKey(metric => metric.GQMetric_ID);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ValuesMetrics>()
            .HasKey(valuesMetrics => new
            {
                valuesMetrics.Value_ID,
                valuesMetrics.GQMetric_ID
            });

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ValuesMetrics>()
            .HasRequired(valuesMetrics => valuesMetrics.Values)
            .WithMany(valueMetrics => valueMetrics.ValuesMetrics)
            .HasForeignKey(valueMetrics => valueMetrics.Value_ID);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<ValuesMetrics>()
            .HasRequired(valuesMetrics => valuesMetrics.GQMetric)
            .WithMany(valueMetrics => valueMetrics.ValuesMetrics)
            .HasForeignKey(valueMetrics => valueMetrics.GQMetric_ID);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Values
{
    public int Values_ID { get; set; }
    public string Values_Name { get; set; }
    public int ValuesNumeric { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ValuesMetrics> ValuesMetrics { get; set; }
}

public class GQMetric
{
    public int GQMetric_ID { get; set; }
    public string GQMetricName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ValuesMetrics> ValuesMetrics { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesMetrics
{
    public int GQMetric_ID { get; set; }
    public int Value_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual GQMetric GQMetric { get; set; }
    public virtual Values Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: SIMPLY AMAZING! Thank you so much!